# Exportar conteúdo em XLS no admin do WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, microsoft-excel, xls

Preciso exportar um conteúdo específico para XLS dentro da área administrativa, e estou usando o seguinte código:

```
$arquivo = 'planilha.xls';

$html = '';
$html .= '<table>';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td colspan="3">Planilha teste</tr>';
$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td><b>Coluna 1</b></td>';
$html .= '<td><b>Coluna 2</b></td>';
$html .= '<td><b>Coluna 3</b></td>';
$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td>L1C1</td>';
$html .= '<td>L1C2</td>';
$html .= '<td>L1C3</td>';
$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td>L2C1</td>';
$html .= '<td>L2C2</td>';
$html .= '<td>L2C3</td>';
$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '</table>';

header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );

echo $html;
exit;
```

Porém quando executo este código em uma página no admin, ele acaba exportando outros conteúdos além do valor da variável `$html`, como menus e links do admin dentro do arquivo XLS.

Como inserir somente o conteúdo retornado pela variável `$html` no arquivo XLS gerado?

Comment: Consegui resolver combinando meu código com este exemplo aqui:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144156/create-dynamic-wordrpess-blank-page?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Oi, robson, pode por favor publicar uma resposta, assim ajuda outros que não falam ingles. Também tenho um script parecido: [How to export comments in WordPress?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82264/12615)

Comment: Olá brasofilo, vc diz publicar uma resposta com o código completo, mostrando como consegui resolver meu problema?

Comment: É, na verdade, sua pergunta tá aqui sem uma resposta/solução publicada abaixo. É legal pra quem visita o SOpt ver a solução aqui mesmo. E como você menciona que resolveu o problema, é uma boa prática responder a própria pergunta, assim além de conseguir ajuda pras suas dúvidas, você também contribui com o site :)

Comment: Entendi... ok, vou postar o código completo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue código completo de como consegui solucionar o problema:

Criei um arquivo chamado "export.php"

```
<?php

ob_start();

global $wpdb;

// Tabela do banco de dados
$minha_tabela = $wpdb->prefix . "tabela_de_registros";

$exportar_resultados = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $minha_tabela ORDER BY id DESC");

// Nome do arquivo que será exportado
$arquivo = 'Relatorio_'.date('dmYHis').'.xls';

// Tabela HTML com o formato da planilha
$html = '';
$html .= '<table border="1">';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td colspan="4" align="center"><b>Relatorio do site '.get_bloginfo('name').'</b></tr>';
$html .= '</tr>';

$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td><b>ID</b></td>';
$html .= '<td><b>Valor 1</b></td>';
$html .= '<td><b>Valor 2</b></td>';
$html .= '<td><b>Valor 3</b></td>';
$html .= '</tr>';

foreach($exportar_resultados as $resultado){

    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$resultado->id.'</td>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$resultado->valor_1.'</td>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$resultado->valor_2.'</td>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$resultado->valor_3.'</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';

}

$html .= '</table>';


// Configurações header para forçar o download
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );

// Envia o conteúdo do arquivo
echo $html;

ob_end_flush();
//exit;

?>
```

função que cria uma página em branco no admin do wordpress (sem menus do admin, links, etc...)

```
function my_menu_pages() {
    $hook = add_submenu_page(null, 'Exportar Relatório', 'Exportar Relatório', 'administrator', 'exportar-relatorio', function() {
    }
    );
    add_action('load-' . $hook, function() {

        require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/export.php"; //chamamos o arquivo export.php
        exit;
    });
}
```

Marquei o primeiro argumento da função `add_submenu_page` como `null`, para evitar que a página de exportação seja acessada através do menu do admin do wordpress, assim, só será acessada diretamente pela url.

Por fim, o botão que faz a exportação dentro do admin do wordpress:

```
<a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=exportar-relatorio' ); ?>" class="button button-primary action">Exportar para XLS</a>
```

Espero que seja útil pra alguém. ;D